# MySql is not working. installed with xampp but now it always shows "loading" bar

Tags: mysql, xampp

No matter what I do I can't get this to work right.

Everything was working fine, then I did a Windows 8 update (not my choice) and it never has worked again.

1. I've reinstalled xampp twice.
2. I've changed the port to 8080 and 4433

I've tried just about everything on SO but haven't seen my exact issue. This is what the screen looks like and I can't do anything. Nothing works.

[image]

Has anyone seen this and does anyone have another suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Did you install xampp in the same driver again? if you did, try another driver of your windows.

Comment: @HamedGhasempour: I just did the install.exe that you download from the site. It never asked about a driver. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: My xamp was installed on D:/. When I tried to install it again in same driver(partition), oopsss. Nothing worked. I changed the windows driver(partition) to C:/ and it worked.

Comment: @HamedGhasempour: Yep, I moved it to D:/ and was able to get it working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install Xamp in another windows partition. In fact, change your partition which is different from the current partition (imagine C:/) and reinstall xampp in a new partition (imagine D:/).